# How to connect snowsql from PC (Windows 10)

Tags: authentication, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, desktop

I  have signed up for 30 day trial version for snowflake, as part of learning I am trying to run the *Snowsql* (client) from my windows desktop. I installed client from snowflake client repository (account name, username and password are all correct).

Got the following error:

```
C:\Users\ugain>snowsql -a vg49826 -u ugainedi
Password:
**250001 (08001): Failed to connect to DB. Verify the account name is correct: vg49826.snowflakecomputing.com:443. HTTP 403: Forbidden
If the error message is unclear, enable logging using -o log_level=DEBUG and see the log to find out the cause. Contact support for further help.
Goodbye!**
```

Appreciate the help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your account using the Snowflake web UI and look at the URL. Since there is no account `vg49826.snowflakecomputing.com`, that means you're running Snowflake somewhere other than on AWS_US_WEST_2. That's the only region that does not include the region in the account name for connection purposes.

Copy the portion of the URL up to but not including "snowflakecomputing.com". It will be something like `vg49826.us-east-1`, `vg49826.east-us-2.azure`, or something similar. Your Snowflake account, for the purposes of connecting to SnowSQL is the portion of the URL after `https://` and before `snowflakecomputing.com` in the web UI URL.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. It worked.